# Открытие в новой вкладке js

Tags: javascript, frontend

Добрый день, возникла задача автоматически нажимать на баннер, но не как обычно.
При нажатии на определенный div на странице требуется имитировать нажатие по iframe правой кнопкой мыши и выбор "открыть в новой вкладке"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: Я бы сказал, что это невозможно, потому что во всех совеременных браузерах есть попап-блокер и я не вижу никакого отличия вашего желания открыть окно от обычного нежелательного попапа.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Открытие в новой вкладке, не блокируется браузерами, если открытие связано с действием пользователя на странице, непосредственный клик по элементу и открытие вкладки кодом, браузер пропустит. Открытие вкладке по таймеру - заблокируется.

Comment: @Bookin Я в курсе. Но автор-то хочет «автоматически», что я понимаю как «без участия человека».

Comment: @AlexeyTen извиняюсь, упустил это